# css gradient bg animation

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I'm trying to make an animated gradient background for a web site as shown below

```css
background: linear-gradient(315deg, #001f3f 0%, #003f7f 50%, #000d3b 74%);
animation: gradient 5s ease forwards;
```

but the problem is that I need the animation to happen once you scroll and before that it needs to just sit in the first color value.

the main issue is that if that's the only background I'm using, then it triggers on reload, and if I put a default background of the starting color and on top of the gradient, when I scroll up it blips to default and looks glitchy. I'm using styled components.

Any tips on a new approach for this problem? Is it even possible to hold the animation at first value until you scroll?

Comment: _is it even possible to hold the animation at first value until you scroll_  Yes. You don't "hold" the animation, but what you can do is set a class on the element *on scroll* that holds the animation. So you have `.class {....}` `.class.started-scrolling-class { animation: gradient 5s ease forwards;}` something like that.